# Radioactive decay : Function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

If we say that the graph of N(t) is non-differentiable then how do we propose to write a differential equation for such a model? Also, I haven't much clearly understood the argument. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The book is saying that technically, N(t) will not be differentiable since it resembles a step function (increasing discretely). They also say that they can pretend it is approximately differentiable to develop a simple model. The differential equations will then be a "close enough" model.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "approximately differentiable"?... And what does that have to do with N being large?

Comment: If we say that N(t) decays by 50% for every unit of t, then the actual function N(t) will look something like N(0) = 100, N(1) = 50, N(2) = 25, N(3) = 12 (or 13). We cannot have N(3) = 12.5 (since we can't have 0.5 of a particle). This makes it difficult for us to come up with a differential model with integral values. Now let's scale up. Suppose N(0) = 10^10+1. Then N(1) = 5*10^9 (and here, we are approximating N(1) - it might be off by some small number). When we come up with a model, we will not worry about being slightly inaccurate (within a tolerance).

Answer (score 1):

In the text, they are saying that in reality, $N(t)$ is a non-differentiable function, since it consists of small, discontinuous steps, but that when these steps are small enough, we can approximate the function to be smooth.

The steps represent nuclei decaying. Imagine if you had $N(0)=10$. Then when one atom decayed, $N(t)$ would decrease with $10\%$ in an instant - that is a very noticeable discontinuity! Now compare this to if $N(0)=10^{23}$. Then the first single decay would result in a decrease of $10^{-21} \%$, which is a decrease so small that one could argue that it's hardly there at all - kind of like with infinitesimals ;)